# Can an orthogonal non-symmetric 3x3 matrix have 3 real eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I was wondering if a non-symmetric orthogonal matrix can have his 3 eigenvalues in the real numbers.

All the 3 real eigenvalues orthogonal matrix i've found are symmetric.

Can someone give me a example?

Comment: Do you meant $3$ *distinct* real eigenvalues? That's impossible.

Comment: An orthogonal matrix will have real eigenvalues if and only if it is symmetric

Comment: No, i meant if no complex eigenvalues could be found in an orthogonal 3x3 non symmetric matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix of the shape $3\times 3$ (and one can make things more general, but i am not willing to type bigger matrices in the sequel...) have modulus one, being real as stated means that these are among $-1, +1$.

If all eigenvalues are equal, then $A$ is diagonalized in the form $A=SDS^{-1}$ with $D=\pm 1$ in the center, so $A=\pm 1$, this is symmetric.

Else, suppose the eigenvalues are $1,1,-1$. (In this order.) (Pass to $-A$ in the case $-1,-1,1$.) Fix $u_1,u_2$ orthogonal eigenvectors for $1$, and some $u_3$ for $-1$. We may and do assume that $u_1,u_2,u_3$ all have norm $1$, so they form an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^3$. We regard the as column vectors.

Using block matrix computations, let $U=[u_1u_2u_3]$ be the matrix pasted together from the vectors as columns, then
$$
AU=A[u_1u_2u_3]
=[\ Au_1\ Au_2\ Au_3\ ]
=[\ u_1\ u_2\ (-u_3)\ ]
=U\begin{bmatrix}
1&&\\&1&\\&&-1\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$
So
$$
A=
U\begin{bmatrix}
1&&\\&1&\\&&-1\end{bmatrix}
U'
$$
is symmetric.

(Note that $U^{-1}=U'$.)

Comment: You're assuming that if $A$ is orthogonal then $A$ is diagonalizable, which requires some form of the spectral theorem

Comment: Another approach, once it's established that orthogonal matrices are diagonalizable, is to note that $A$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues in $\{-1,1\}$ if and only if $A^2 = I$.

Comment: I was trying to put some details, so that the argumentation works without heavy metal stuff. Where i'm assuming the diagonalizability?

Comment: "Fix $u_1,u_2$ orthogonal eigenvectors for $1$, and some $u_3$ for $-1$"

Comment: The generalized eigenspace for $1$ has dimension $2$. A problem may only occur if the true eigenspace has dimension one. Then pick $u_1$. Also $u_3$... and eigenvectors for different eigenvalues are orthogonal, so $u_3$ is not the problem. Passing to the quotient space $W=\Bbb R^3/\langle u_1,u_3\rangle$ we get some $u_2$ in $\Bbb R^3$ with $Au_2 = u_2+su_1$. Then $(u_2,u_1)=(Au_2,Au_1)=(u_2+su_1,u_1)$, so $s=0$.

Comment: that's a neat approach, seems to work. You should add that to your answer then.

Comment: I don't get why the last matrix product equals a symmetric matrix

Comment: We have $A=UDU'$ with a diagonal, thus symmetric $D$. Then $A'=(UDU')'=(U')'D'U'=UDU'=A$.